# Using noVNC client to connect to proxmox

Tags: python, websocket, proxmox, novnc

i am trying to use the [noVNC HTML5 Client](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC) to connect via noVNC to a vm running on my proxmox server.

I am using [proxmoxer](https://pypi.org/project/proxmoxer/) as client for the proxmox API.

first i log in to proxmox via the API to get the vnc tocket. After that, i call the vncwebsocket endpoint to open the websocket connection like described [here](https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/api-viewer/index.html#/nodes/%7Bnode%7D/qemu/%7Bvmid%7D/vncwebsocket).

Here is the code for this:

```
node, vm = 'pve-03', '497'
proxmox = ProxmoxAPI(PROXMOX_HOST, user=PROXMOX_USER, password=PROXMOX_PASSWORD, verify_ssl=False)
proxmox.login()
vnc_res = proxmox.nodes(node).qemu(vm).vncproxy().post(websocket="1")
vnc_ticket = quote_plus(vnc_res['ticket'])
ws_res = proxmox.nodes(node).qemu(vm).vncwebsocket().get(
    vncticket=vnc_res['ticket'],
    port=vnc_res['port']
)
```

Now i build the websocket url for the noVNC client and open it in my browser.

```
port = ws_res['port']
url = f'http://localhost/noVNC/vnc.html?autoconnect=1&encrypt=1&path=&host={PROXMOX_HOST}&port={port}&password={vnc_ticket}'
```

But the noVNC client shows: failed to connect to server.
Here is what i see in the network tab:
[image: Network request in chrome dev tools]

I searched a lot how to get it to work but with no resulsts. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanky in advance